# Enable/disable kendo ui control dynamically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-combobox

I want to enable/disable a kendo combobox based on the user's selection from a checkbox, which I am storing in a variable.

I already tried setting the variable to the enable property, but this is useful only when the control is being built-in.

Does anybody know If I can do this while creating the control?

```
<div id="fund" class="col-xs-3">
 input class="required" data-bind="title: $parent.selectedFund, 
  kendoComboBox: {
   placeholder: 'Start typing to search...',
   value: $parent.test,
   widget: $parent.searchSource,
   dataTextField: 'managerName',
   dataValueField: 'managerId',
   filter: 'contains',
   autoBind: false,
   minLength: 3,
   enable: overrideGlobalMapping, //this does not work for me even though the variable holds the correct value
   change: function(){ if(this.value() && this.selectedIndex == -1) 
   {
    setTimeout(function () {$parent.selectedManagerId(null);}, 100);}},
    dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
    read: $parent.retrieveManager
   }
  }
 }" />
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap your comboBox definition in a function.  Call the function only trigger by the checkbox change event.

Comment: Since you are already using bindings, can I suggest you take a look at the [MVVM demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/mvvm) which does exactly what you want; it binds the enabled state of a combo and the checked state of a checkbox to a single boolean property on a kendo observable object. The two then track together, and could also be programatically changed like this `viewModel.set("isEnabled", true);`

Comment: @FrozenButcher: this is what I thought as a work-around, and it is what I actually ended up doing.                                        Thank you.

Comment: @JoeGlover: I tried doing that, but since we handle MVVM in a more complex way (more than one model linked to the view model), it was too much work just for this. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion, I am taking this into account for new implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the kendo combox definition in a function, so it now looks likes this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="overrideGlobalMappingCheck" onclick="SetFundsCombobox()" data-bind="checked: overrideGlobalMapping, enable: $root.canConfirmMapping" />
```

The kendo combobox is still wrapped and has an id, which I later use to manipulate it in javascript:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" id="funds">
    <input class="required" data-bind="title: $parent.selectedFund, 
        kendoComboBox: {
            placeholder: 'Start typing to search...',
            value: $parent.selectedManagerId,
        ...
    }" />
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript function bound to the onclick checkbox's event:

```
function SetFundsCombobox() {
    var fundsDiv = document.getElementById('funds');
    var inputSelector = fundsDiv.getElementsByClassName('k-input');
    var span = fundsDiv.getElementsByTagName('span');

    if (document.getElementById('overrideGlobalMappingCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('funds').disabled = false;
        inputSelector[0].disabled = false;
        span[1].classList.remove("k-state-disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('funds').disabled = true;
        inputSelector[0].disabled = true;
        span[1].classList.add("k-state-disabled");
    }
};
```

I'd have rather preferred to perform this via the view model, but it works for now.

**EDIT:**

I've been able to do this the right way (following the MVVM pattern), so now rather than wrapping the kendo combo box in a function, I added the following function in the view model:

```
$scope.overrideGlobalMappingChecker = ko.computed(function () {
    if ($scope.entityMapping()) {
        var checkboxChecked = $scope.entityMapping().overrideGlobalMapping();
        $("#funds .k-input").prop('disabled', !checkboxChecked);
        if (!checkboxChecked) {
            $scope.selectedFundId(null);
        }
    }
});
```

So now, what the html only needs is the definition of the id in the div containing the combo box:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" id="funds">
    <input data-bind="title: $parent.selectedFundName, kendoComboBox: {
    autoBind: false,
    ...
    }" />
</div>
```

And that's it, it's a much cleaner/correct way to handle this.